# The highlight colour for interested tags

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-watching

Hi, I would like to make a comment about the pale yellow highlight that is used for questions with tags that you're interested in on the stackoverflow.com website.  I'm colour blind and can hardly tell the difference between the highlighted and the non-highlighted questions.  To make matters worse, it is almost impossible to see on some laptop displays and you have to adjust the angle of your screen to pick up the difference.

Would it be possible to increase the contrast between the highlighted and non-highlighted areas?

Comment: Depending on what browser you're using, some people on Meta can whip up a userstyle/script in a couple of minutes to solve that. Do you use Chrome/Firefox, with Greasemonkey or Stylish?

Answer (score 5):

It's a very simple change so I've just wrote a Userstyle and uploaded it. This would require the use of (I think) Internet Explorer, Opera, Chrome or Firefox, with or without the Stylish extension.

The style can be found [here](http://userstyles.org/styles/36297)

The code, in its entirety:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document url-prefix(http://stackoverflow.com){

.tagged-interesting {
  background-color: #ddd !important;
}

}
```

That's it. It changes the background color of interested questions to `#dddddd`, which is this color below:

[image]

---

**Installation**

1. Go to [here](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) and install the Stylish extension for Google Chrome
2. Go to [here](http://userstyles.org/styles/36297) and install the script with the install button
3. Et voilà! The interesting question highlight color is now gray instead of yellow.

Comment: Where would this file go?  Would I need extensions?  BTW, I use Chrome.

Comment: @Cthutu Yes you would. See my update.

Comment: @YiJiang Sorry but it doesn't work for me, nothing changed :/

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you could use and modify [alconja's greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/double-intensity-shading-for-questions-with-1-interesting-tags/49724#49724) to change the tag-highlighting colour.